# Custom Token Response on Token Endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, token, identityserver4

Is there a way to achieve the below response on Token Endpoint?

```
{
  "access_token": "reirhnfslker3874hdjw8o",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "43wi9jd38du83wjd38d",
  "id_token": "3yc3u4mc83u4820ic2i3409muc28yc28h532y...",
  "custom_response": "test"
}
```

I already tried using ICustomTokenRequestValidator but it didn't worked

```
public class CustomTokenRequestValidator : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
    {
        public async Task<CustomTokenRequestValidationContext> ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
        {
            context.Result.CustomResponse = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "custom_response", "test" } };

            return context;
        }

        Task ICustomTokenRequestValidator.ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
        {
            return ValidateAsync(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: JWTs are a standard for a reason. Instead of trying to modify the JWT, which will make you have non-standard clients and servers (code you will have to do and maintain manually), find the appropriate way of adding the values you need to it.

Comment: The client wants to get the value of 'custome_response' from Token Endpoint. Can you please suggest a better way to add the value?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `ITokenResponseGenerator` interface and either store information in the Custom entries property of the Token Response [Model](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/047a6bcd70359d931a48f2c9f3f5e72263afcdf5/src/IdentityServer4/src/ResponseHandling/Models/TokenResponse.cs)

Or just have this interface return your own version of TokenResponse model